# export 'getToken' (imported as 'getToken$1') was not found in 'firebase/app-check' (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm developing an application in angular (Angular CLI: 13.1.4) and when integrating Firebase, I'm getting some export errors (given below), any one please suggest me an solution

> app.module.js

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/storage";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/firestore";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/database";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    PlaceDetailComponent,
    PlacesComponent,
    AdminIndexComponent,
    AdminPlaceComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.config),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,

    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> package.json

[image]

> Error

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-app-check.js:106:27-37 - Error: export 'getToken' (imported as 'getToken$1') was not found in 'firebase/app-check' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-app-check.js:107:37-57 - Error: export 'initializeAppCheck' (imported as 'initializeAppCheck$1') was
not found in 'firebase/app-check' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-app-check.js:108:33-49 - Error: export 'onTokenChanged' (imported as 'onTokenChanged$1') was not found in 'firebase/app-check' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-app-check.js:109:45-73 - Error: export 'setTokenAutoRefreshEnabled' (imported as 'setTokenAutoRefreshEnabled$1') was not found in 'firebase/app-check' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:16:98-109 - Error: export 'isSupported' (imported as 'isSupported') was not found in 'firebase/analytics' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:17:98-111 - Error: export 'isSupported' (imported as 'isSupported$1') was not found in 'firebase/messaging' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire.js:18:104-117 - Error: export 'isSupported' (imported as 'isSupported$2') was not found in 'firebase/remote-config' (module has no exports)

× Failed to compile.

Comment: Found anything? I'm also stuck in the same. Happened after I tried to update the version of @angular/fire and firebase. Reverting to previous versions also not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `npm install` on the terminal and the issue goes away. There may be some deprecated libraries that are causing this. For me, angularfire2 caused this issue.